# When i deploy project on heroku db doesnt work normal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

So i have this code in my mode

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: users
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  name       :string
#  surname    :string
#  user_id    :integer
#  count      :integer          default(0)
#  was        :boolean          default(FALSE)
#  qrcode     :string
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
#

class User < ApplicationRecord
    validates :name, presence: true
    validates :surname, presence: true
    validates :user_id, presence: true
    after_create :generate_qr

    private
    def generate_qr
        ian = User.find(id)
        ian.update_attribute(:qrcode, "https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?size=150x150&data=" + user_id.to_s)
        # update_attribute(:qrcode, "https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?size=150x150&data=" + user_id.to_s)
    end


end
```

Its work fine and generate qr code on my local host. But when i deploy on heroku i have this errors in heroku logs.

```
2018-06-30T14:23:37.200657+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-06-30T14:23:37.200507 #4]  INFO -- : [56b953ac-5a43-4b25-980d-f2bc5c53883a]   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"mBkhE7alyyKGtS4v+tnW2Vpg6c1z0kwQfbnftqTWdSukTpre29vkqVmeuVoGR7NJzs0EoxiQv0rS+WzJ4hUSOw==", "user"=>{"name"=>"fdsfds", "surname"=>"fdsfdsfds", "user_id"=>"53454"}, "commit"=>"Create User"}
2018-06-30T14:23:37.204598+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2018-06-30T14:23:37.204527 #4] DEBUG -- : [56b953ac-5a43-4b25-980d-f2bc5c53883a]    (1.1ms)  BEGIN
2018-06-30T14:23:37.207575+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2018-06-30T14:23:37.207496 #4] DEBUG -- : [56b953ac-5a43-4b25-980d-f2bc5c53883a]   User Create (1.5ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("name", "surname", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["name", "fdsfds"], ["surname", "fdsfdsfds"], ["user_id", 53454], ["created_at", "2018-06-30 14:23:37.204956"], ["updated_at", "2018-06-30 14:23:37.204956"]]
2018-06-30T14:23:37.214137+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2018-06-30T14:23:37.214060 #4] DEBUG -- : [56b953ac-5a43-4b25-980d-f2bc5c53883a]   User Load (1.3ms)
  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 7], ["LIMIT", 1]]
2018-06-30T14:23:37.215729+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2018-06-30T14:23:37.215664 #4] DEBUG -- : [56b953ac-5a43-4b25-980d-f2bc5c53883a]    (1.1ms)  ROLLBACK
2018-06-30T14:23:37.224955+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-06-30T14:23:37.224881 #4]  INFO -- : [56b953ac-5a43-4b25-980d-f2bc5c53883a] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 24ms (ActiveRecord: 6.1ms)
2018-06-30T14:23:37.225904+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-06-30T14:23:37.225838 #4] FATAL -- : [56b953ac-5a43-4b25-980d-f2bc5c53883a]
2018-06-30T14:23:37.226043+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-06-30T14:23:37.225990 #4] FATAL -- : [56b953ac-5a43-4b25-980d-f2bc5c53883a] NoMethodError (undefined method `qrcode=' for #<User:0x00000004fd1d68>):
2018-06-30T14:23:37.226091+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-06-30T14:23:37.226046 #4] FATAL -- : [56b953ac-5a43-4b25-980d-f2bc5c53883a]
2018-06-30T14:23:37.226146+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-06-30T14:23:37.226103 #4] FATAL -- : [56b953ac-5a43-4b25-980d-f2bc5c53883a] app/models/user.rb:25:in `generate_qr'
```

Someone please help. I dont know where is error. Its work fine on my localhost.

Comment: Seems like you didn't run migrations on heroku.

Comment: Try something like `heroku run rake db:migrate` and your other configuration for app and whatever environment you are in.